# Test rig and the balancing algorithm

Tags: matlab

**Uncertainty analyses**

The automatic balancing algorithm estimates the position of the center of mass basing on IMU measurements (accelerometer and gyro). Since the measurements are affected by sensor noise, then the resultant estimate will be in turn affected by uncertainty. Quantify the amount of uncertainty using the following two methods:

- Monte Carlo
- First Order Second Moment (FOSM)

Assume an offset of the center of mass with respect to center of rotation and levels of noise of the sensors as follows:

**Case 1 (high noise)**

```
RG_SYS = [0.002, -0.002, -0.005] [m] 
noiseGyro = 2 [rad/s] noiseIMU = 1 [m/s^2]
```

**Case 2 (moderate noise)**

```
RG_SYS = [0.002, -0.002, -0.005] [m] 
noiseGyro = 0.5 [rad/s] noiseIMU = 0.05 [m/s^2]
```

**Case 3 (low noise)**

```
RG_SYS = [0.002, -0.002, -0.005] [m] 
noiseGyro = 0.01 [rad/s] noiseIMU = 0.01 [m/s^2]
```

Comment: So you provided us with a task, probably homework. What you expect? Show use your effort, what you did so far, etc.

Comment: I need to implemet Monte Carlo function on Matlab, into this program and I don`t know where I need to put it. ¿Do you know?

Comment: Just place the code under parameters you mentioned in question. If you encounter any error, show it here, so we can help you. If you need general information you can look [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/mc2013/lec4.pdf) or [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55306-monte-carlo-estimation-examples-with-matlab-implementation)